# Retry on query error in specific knex connection

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, express, knex.js

I have a REST API built on Express.js, Knex.js, and PostgreSQL (with a read-only replica). I want to implement the ability to retry a query on a specific error for a specific instance (for example, only for the replica). I don't want to rewrite any existing code; instead, I aim to create something like a 'plug-in' that wraps the Knex connection and handles the query errors.

Currently, my implementation looks like this:

```
const getKnex = (type: 'primary' | 'replica') => {
    return type === 'replica' ? knexReplica : knex;
}
```

I want to use it like this:

```
const getKnex = (type: 'primary' | 'replica') => {
    return type === 'replica' ? knexWithRetryOnError(knexReplica) : knex;
}
```

I tried to replace function in knex instance

```
const knexWithRetryOnError = (knex: Knex) => {
    knex.select = function (...args: any) { ... } // just for example
    return knex;
}
```

but It didn't work.

Also I tried to catch errors using knex.on('query-error', (error) => { ... })
But then It is not possible to retry the query correctly.